# No log4j2 configuration file found error occurs unless log4j2.xml is in two folders simultaneously

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have a project structure like this:

```
tomcat
    webapps
        ProjectName
            src
                main
                    java
                    resources
                            log4j2.xml
                    webapp
                        WEB-INF
                          web.xml
                          lib
                          classes
                            com
                               mysite
                                     MyClass.class
                            log4j2.xml
```

So, there are three possible scenarios:

1. `log4j2.xml` is located in both **resources** and **classes** folders
2. `log4j2.xml` is located only in **resources**
3. `log4j2.xml` is located only in **classes**

In the *first* scenario the code that I run from `MyClass.java`:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
logger.debug("Debug log message");
logger.info("Info log message");
logger.error("Error log message");
```

works fine.

In the *second* scenario it doesn't work in most cases, but sometimes works and seem to copy the file to **classes** folder. It seems to only work-and-copy if I've tried the *thrid* scenario right before.

In the *third* scenario doesn't work and deletes the file from **classes**.

By 'work' I mean prints out the debug messages, by doesn't work I mean prints out the error `No log4j2 configuration file found error`.

I thought it would look for the file in the Project's folders, and once found, would use it with no issues. But here it seems to only work when it's in both **resources** and **classes** folders and I don't understand why. There seems to be some serious magic at play and I'm completely out of the loop.

**EDIT**: I work in Idea Intellij and have a `pom.xml` with dependencies and some build stuff (unrelated to `log4j2`) specified. There's `log4j2` dependency in there, however, there's nothing about `log4j2` in the build tag or anywhere else in the file. I'm new to Maven, but it seems to me it shouldn't matter in this case? I don't run the `build` command. I right-click on `MyClass.java` (*not* on Maven's 'Run Maven Build' green arrow) and press the green arrow's `Run MyClass.main()`.

**EDIT**: I do have this line in `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
     <outputDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes</outputDirectory>
     ...
</build>
```

Which affects file's compilation's directory, so that might be of influence.

**EDIT**: Also, I'm reading [this log4j2 tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j-2-xml-configuration-example/) and they say it's enough to place the `log4j2.xml` *anywhere* in the application's classpath. Putting `log4j2.xml` just in `resources` works fine for them.

And Idea Intellij knows about the `resources` folders in my case, when I go to Project Structure - Modules there's this:

[image]

Comment: What IDE / build tool are you using? If correctly setup, the IDE is in control of the `classes` folder and will keep the `log4j2.xml` updated from the original in the `resources` folder. But that's how IDEs work. If you use a build tool (Ant, Maven, Gradle, ...), then that copy happens during the build, but again, only if correctly configured.

Comment: @Andreas Please, see edit.

Comment: You're pointing your runtime at the wrong directory. Everything should be being copied or compiled into `target/`.

Comment: @chrylis This is the Java's Tomcat webapp setup that I've seen in many tutorials. There's nothing wrong with it. If `log4j2` only looks in `target`, why do scenarios 1 and 2 (sometimes) work?

Comment: chrylis is talking about your `outputDirectory` - maven by default uses the `target` [directory](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for all build output. The directory you specified is where source files should go, not output files. You're having classpath problems in that when you're running your code the classpath does not have the log4j2 configuration file. You should find out what is included in your classpath and make sure log4j2's config file is in there.

Comment: Alternatively you could define the `log4j.configurationFile` system property per the [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration)

Comment: @D.B. Well, I use a structure like [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html). I'm reluctant to change it, because I've spent a long time making it work. Here's what I don't understand: `You're having classpath problems in that when you're running your code the classpath does not have the log4j2 configuration file`. If it doesn't look in my `classes` and `resources`, then it woldn't have found it when the file is in **both** those folders. All 3 scenarios would have been invalid. But the 1st and 2nd still work - why?

Comment: @D.B. And I tried putting it in `ProjectName/target`, it wouldn't work unless in `resources` and `classes` as well. I'll check out `log4j.configurationFile` though.

Comment: Note in general that this sort of project setup is considered obsolete. Modern standalone applications such as Spring Boot, Dropwizard, and Micronaut eliminate lots of this exact hassle.

Comment: @chrylis Right now I'm playing with older technologies like servlets, so yeah, it makes sense that the setup could be outdated. It's a shame I'd have to change it when moving to Spring Boot. It's always long hours trying to make it work ;(